# Cordova inAppBrowser : Display Custom title instead of URL of page

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Is there any way to display custom title instead of URL in headerbar of inAppBrowser. What attribute should be added ?

```
 $scope.openBrowser = function() {
         // Open in app browser
 window.open('https://devprivasera.com/#/login','_self','location=yes'); 
};
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. I try to add text in the toolbar but it seems no option property is available for that. did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set Default Options

```
var defaultOptions = { location: 'no', clearcache: 'no', toolbar: 'no'};
```

use cordova plugin [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for iOS.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://devprivasera.com/#/login', '_blank', 'toolbar=no');
```

Check out the other options [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen).